# WCF client connecting to Java SOAP web service using WS-Security

Tags: wcf, soap, ws-security

I'm having a problem with a .NET WCF client connecting to a Java web service using SOAP 1.1. The service requires both transport level encryption over SSL and SOAP security using the WS-Security protocol, both using the same certificate. I have the certificate installed and I can connect to the server however, I get a HTTP 500 response when I post the request.

I have been able to compare the SOAP produced by WCF with a working example from the developers of the web service. The WCF SOAP message has additional Timestamp and BinarySecurityToken elements which don't occur in the supplied example. I know almost nothing about WS-Security and very little about WCF and so I'm hoping that someone can point me in the correct direction.

Here is the configuration section for my application:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="JavaServiceSoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://service/endpoint"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="JavaServiceSoapBinding"
          contract="MyCode.MyService" name="MyServicePort" behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endpointBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" findValue="A1A1A1A1" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"/>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And this is the example SOAP header I have from the parter responsible for the service:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservice.connector.speechanalytics.ept.avaya.com/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <ds:Signature Id="Signature-5" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-6">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>blablabla=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
          blablabla=
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-blablabla">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STRId-blablabla" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <ds:X509Data>
              <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Dept,OU=Product,O=Company,L=Location,ST=BLA,C=BLA</ds:X509IssuerName>
                <ds:X509SerialNumber>1319578157</ds:X509SerialNumber>
              </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
            </ds:X509Data>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-6" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
```

and this is the SOAP message that WCF is producing:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2012-05-21T15:02:36.448Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2012-05-21T15:07:36.448Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-abd451ed-9bff-4cd0-b9a6-38fcd6bf9e8b-1" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">blablabla==</o:BinarySecurityToken>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <Reference URI="#_0">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>+blablabla=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>blablabla=</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-abd451ed-9bff-4cd0-b9a6-38fcd6bf9e8b-1"/>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have any details on why the server fails? messages do not have to be exactly the same. try to see if the http 500 body contains something, or if the vendor can tell you from the logs.

next revert to a custombinding instead of a basichttpbinding (do this [online automatically](http://webservices20.cloudapp.net/)) and on the security element binding add attribute includeTimestamp="false".

try with this first (and get message). workign w/o BinarySecurityToken is also possible but slightly more complex at this stage.

Comment: Thanks for your help. No details in 500 message and nothing in the logs. I've tried your tool and the generated config results in the same SOAP message. Is there something else I can configure on the custom binding to make the SOAP use the correct security mechanism?

Comment: please publish how your soap request looks now and how the response looks like (even if there are no details ther must be some soap:Fault xml)

Comment: The structure of the SOAP request is identical to one I posted above. The HTTP response is get is:

HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(7.1.6.v20100715)

There is no response body and so no SOAP envelope or fault.

Comment: not sure you applied my suggestion from the answer - the soap in your message has a timestamp so you should use includeTimestamp=false on a custom binding

Comment: Sorry, yes I did apply your suggestion but I get an exception message from WCF: "System.InvalidOperationException: Signing without primary signature requires timestamp". Any ideas?

Comment: please publish the custom binding you use. you should have authenticationMode=mutualCertificate. You should also define some service certificate on the proxy (even a dummy one or the same on you use for the client)

Comment: Now resolved. In addition to the above, the authenticationMode of the generated custom binding security element had to be set to "MutualCertificate". The service certificate had to be declared in client credentials section. Default behaviour is to encrypt the message which is not required here. Solution was to edit reference.cs with attribute ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign on the contract.

Comment: Could you please post your client config?