# Calling Java SOAP 1.1 Service by WCF Client

Tags: java, c#, .net, wcf, ws-security

Why a SOAP1.1 Web Service written in JAVA may not recognize a valid cert passed by WCF client?

We are getting 500 error from the service indicating that the service doesn't trust our cert. Can it be something to do with the WCF implementation of SOAP standard differing from what Java service expects to see?

Here's the WCF config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ourCert">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="MyCompany"/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpSoap11" >
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://{site}.com/site.wsdl"
                binding="customBinding"
                behaviorConfiguration="ourCert"
                bindingConfiguration="wsHttpSoap11"
                contract="ServiceContract">
      </endpoint>
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>

</configuration>
```

Comment: 500 would simply mean an internal server error.  Do you have a log showing that the internal server error is a certificate trust issue or is that an assumption?

Comment: I recommend use glassfish metro for generation java client. It declares compatibility with WCF https://metro.java.net/guide/ch01.html#ahiar

Comment: 500 is just their way of letting us know that something went wrong. W'e no access to the logs on a service side otherwise it wouldn't be a problem:)

Comment: Ok, it will be difficult to know what the problem is without some solid logging info, unless someone is telling you that the issue is for sure a certificate trust problem... in which case, a certificate needs to be shared and imported.  You can download their cert with Firefox (google the process) and import it on your end.

Comment: that's right. I was hoping for a 'known problem' to exist when supplying a trusted cert from WCF client to a Java WS. WCF is extremally fexible for supporting different combinations of security settings, the config I attached has one of the most straightforward setups, which may or may not suffice.

Comment: Looks pretty similar to this case: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10689583/5280532

Comment: Don't you have a problem with the certicate not being in the java side store ?

Comment: That was the first assumption but we were assured that the cert'd been added. if we call it with a knowingly untrusted cert we get a different error.

Comment: You have given your binding a name of "wsHttpSoap11" which suggests that you are expecting to use some of the WS-* standards. Your binding is equivalent to using <basicHttpBinding> with security mode set to transport. If the service really does need things like message security (some of the WS-* standards such as WS-Security) then your binding won't work. You've also specified the endpoint to be the url to the .wsdl which I suspect is incorrect. Have you tried using "Add Service Reference" and using the .wsdl url to auto generate the client and config?

Answer (score 1):

The certificate is validated against a trust chain so the generating framework is not relevant. Also note you use a transport level certificate so SOAP is less likely to be the source of error.

I suggest you do the following:

1. Build a working java client to this service (either generate a certificate using openssl or use the one you have if it's in jks format). Verify the client is working.
2. Convert the jks certificate to pfx and use it with a WCF client. The WCF client should now also be working.

If WCF still fails than compare the outgoing SOAP generated by the java and wcf clients (you can use fiddler to capture it). This might hint on other differences (maybe you actually need a message certificate and not transport,  maybe your soap version is mismatched, etc).

Comment: thanks for that - but we've no control over the processes on a service side. we were told that our cert is trusted by the service. the issue is likely down to miscommunication between WCF client and Java service. Just wanted to know  what's the potential problem - i.e. misinterpretation. of WS standards by WCF or something else

Comment: in this case create a working java client and compare its output to the wcf output

Comment: also note if indeed only transport certificate is used that you can debug this issue by initiating an HttpRequest or WebClient to the server (error happens on transport level even before any soap becomes relevant)

Comment: Using SOAP UI we were able to identify the problem by comparing SOAP messages produce by WCF and SOAP UI. The solution was to use WSE 3.0.